# Selecting an element with multiple classes in python lxml using xpath

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, xpath, lxml

I was trying to scrape a website using python request and lxml. I could easily select the elements with single class using `html.xpath()` but I can't figure out how to select the elements with multiple class.

I used some code like this to select the elements in page with class "title":

`page.xpath('//a[@class="title"]')`

However, I couldn't select elements with multiple classes. I checked some few codes. I tried to study xpath but it seemes like `lxml.html.xpath()` works different, may be it's my lack of understanding. I tried few codes which didnt' work for me. They are given below.

**HTML code**

```
<a href="https://www.lovemycosmetic.de/skin1004-madagascar-centella-ampoule-30ml-" class="info text-center" title="SKIN1004 Madagascar Centella Ampoule 30ml"> <strong class="supplier"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">SKIN1004</font></font></strong><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">SKIN1004 Madagascar Centella Ampoule 30ml</font></font></a>
```

**Test 1:**

`page.xpath('//a[@class="info text-center"]')`

**Test 2:**

`page.xpath("//a[@class='info text-center']")`

**Test 3:**

`page.xpath('//a[@class="info.text-center"]')`

**Test 4:**

`page.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'info') and contains(@class, 'text-center')]")`

I did couple more tests too but I forgot to save the code. It will be great to know how to select elements with multiple classes using `lxml.html.xpath()`.

Comment: post the html snippet you are trying to parse...

Comment: @Alexander I have edited my question. Would you mind checking it.

Comment: Not the python code... the html.  Either a post the portion that contains the element you are trying to extract or a link to the website that contains it.  The reason I want to see the html is because you test1 test2  all look accurate, but without seeing the html its impossible to say why they aren't working

Comment: Your Test 1. should work fine... It does for me

Comment: Test2 works for me. `a = page.xpath('//a[@class="info text-center"]') print(a[0].text)`

Answer (score 1):

NB as far as XPath is concerned, the `class` attribute's value is a string like any other. It doesn't automatically parse the value as a list of space-delimited tokens, as a CSS selector would. In later versions of XPath you have the function `contains-token()` but `lxml` supports XPath 1.0 in which you basically have to tokenize the `class` value yourself.

If your `class` values are literally `info text-center` then you can test it with the predicate `[@class="info text-center"]`, but that won't match a `class` value of e.g. `text-center info` or `info text-center foo bar`. I'd recommend you use the XPath `contains()` function, e.g.

```xml
//a[contains(@class, "info")][contains(@class, "text-center")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your test1 and test2 should both work fine, this is the code I used to get the results.

```py
from lxml.html import etree
root = etree.fromstring('<a href="https://www.lovemycosmetic.de/skin1004-madagascar-centella-ampoule-30ml-" class="info text-center" title="SKIN1004 Madagascar Centella Ampoule 30ml"> <strong class="supplier"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">SKIN1004</font></font></strong><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">SKIN1004 Madagascar Centella Ampoule 30ml</font></font></a>')
elem = root.xpath('//a[@class="info text-center"]')[0]
url = elem.xpath('./@href')[0]
print(elem, url)
```

OUTPUT:

```
<Element a at 0x1ef01509940> https://www.lovemycosmetic.de/skin1004-madagascar-centella-ampoule-30ml-
```